# When loading images to raw image there is a slight small delay, when it starts over again anyway to avoid the delay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's working really good but still there is a small delay in the **update** when it's starting over again the loop.  It's almost perfect smooth looping. I'm not sure what is making this delay and how to avoid it.

Maybe the problem is that the last image is black. I did this in blender that both first frame and last frame are black. Can this cause a delay effect?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class StreamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
    public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
    public RawImage image;

    void Start()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\tmp");
        // since you use ToLower() the capitalized version are quite redundant btw ;)
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".ogg" };
        FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

        if (!image)
        {
            //Get Raw Image Reference
            image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        }

        frames = GetTextures(info);
    }

    private Texture[] GetTextures(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
    {
        var output = new Texture[fileInfos.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfos[i].FullName);
            output[i] = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            if (!ImageConversion.LoadImage((Texture2D)output[i], bytes, false))
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Could not load image from {fileInfos.Length}!", this);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
        image.texture = frames[index]; //Change The Image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending textures from RAM to GPU **every frame** is neither terribly ideal nor needed really.

You can upload **all** textures to GPU at `Start()`. And then use `Update()` just to **occasionally** update `MaterialPropertyBlock` (or other kind of lightweight pointer GPU understands) to tell which (previously uploaded) texture to render from now on.

---

[Texture2D.Apply()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) sends texture data from (CPU) RAM to GPU. Hence this will upload all frames:

```
frames = GetTextures(info);
foreach( var frame in frames )
    frame.Apply( updateMipmaps:true , makeNoLongerReadable:true );
```

---

To find out which textures are black:

```
for( int i=0 ; i<frames.Length ; i++ )
{
    var frame = frames[i];
    if( IsItAllBlack(frame) )
        Debug.Log($"frame #{i} is all black");
}

bool IsItAllBlack ( Texture2D tex )
{
    var pixels = tex.GetPixels();
    foreach( var col in pixels )
        if( (col.r+col.g+col.b)>0 )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

Btw: Remember to release memory used by those textures once they are no longer needed:

```
foreach( var frame in frames )
    Destroy(frame);
```

It doesn't happen automatically when texture is loaded manually from code.

Comment: `foreach( var frame in frames ) frame.Apply(true,true);`

Comment: but change `Texture[] frames`to `Texture2D[] frames` first

Comment: Ok and what should I do then in the Update ?

Comment: Test it. It may be all good already. Because `image.texture` probably uses MaterialPropertyBlock overrides internally. Another simple option would be to modify it's material with `image.material.mainTexture = frames[index];`

Comment: I tested it with the original image.texture = frames[index]; but it seems now that it's turning black for a second or less when it's ending playing then start again. The frames per seconds is set to 30 since I don't want it to move too fast. Even if I set it to 60 frames per second you can still see it getting black when it's ending and then starting over again.

Comment: Here is a link for a very short video clip I recorded my unity project with the animated images you can see what I mean it's getting black when it's getting to the last image and start over again.  If you pause on second 0:13 you will see what I mean it's getting black.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKMH9rvKIAQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: and a link for my code how it looks like now. https://pastebin.com/1wRkh9w4

Comment: `Black` is a color when texture loading fails (silently, no error messages) if Im not mistaken. So please make sure all frames were loaded successfully first

Comment: I say this, because [ImageConversion.LoadImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html) `Loads PNG/JPG image`s only. And will return default color when attempting to load unsupported file format.

Comment: Now the video is public https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kobuJ_Cjj8s&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I recommend you remove `.ogg` file format from `string[] extensions` because it well may be causing that black image (since it's no `png` nor `jpg` but **audio file**)

Comment: I tested now and I see that from frame 119 including and until frame 1 including the frames are black.  119 is the last frame there are 120 frames overall.  but in blender where I created it there are 120 frames and none of them is black.  Strange.

Comment: I tried to remove the .ogg this is not the problem.

Comment: Where do you destroy the frames ? In the start or in the update ?

Comment: No, no - we need those frames in `Start` and `Update`. Do it in [OnDestroy()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) for example.

Comment: Lets make another test. How can I make that the script will start playing from frame 3 and will end at frame 118 there are 120 frames but the index start from 0 so I want it to  start from index 2 and to end at index 118 and then next loop the same to start from index 2 end at index 118 I see that some images are black on my hard drive so I want to jump over them.

Comment: `int index = (int)( Time.time * framesPerSecond ) % frames.Length;`
`index = (int) Mathf.Lerp( 2 , 118 , (float)index/(float)(frames.Length-1) );` should do the trick